# Spontaneously appearing and disappearing command line windows in Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, command-line, malware, malware-detection

I run Windows 10 (Version 1607, Build 14393.969) with up-to-dated Bitdefender Total Security 2017 and MalwareBytes Anti-Malware Home (Premium). There is no pirated software installed on the computer.

Less than 15 minutes ago, I saw 2 command line windows opening and closing very quickly on their own. I was just browsing the web and had **not** just restarted the machine. The first window appeared and disappeared too quickly so I couldn't see what was its content. For the second one, I only managed to see the words "ubuntu" and "multiverse" before the window closed by itself. The only "linux-related" things I have on this machine is Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and TightVNC with the latter running in the background.

How do I please figure out what happened? Specifically, which program / process opened those command line windows and, if possible, what command lines were being run? I saw this earlier post [here](https://superuser.com/q/1051939) and the comments focused on programs / processes that run on startup but I haven't restarted this machine for some time. I also installed [ConEmu](https://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) (Ver 161206) but so far has been unable to follow the instructions in the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1101201).

Comment: next time search a bit. it was already answered several time, that sysmon logs all program start activity.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to install [SysMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/sysmon) and wait until this happens again. Then check the event logs. It will show the full command line of the process and the parent process which started it.