# Is there a way to filter the command history in Windows using cmder?

Tags: windows-10, grep, history, cmder

In Linux I can doing something like `history | grep abc` and that will only bring up the commands that start with 'abc'.  With Windows in cmder, I can bring up the history of commands with the `history` command, but I can't find a way to filter it down by the first few letters of the command.  There seems to be no equivalent of `|` and `grep`.

Comment: Here is a similar thread discussed before, please check if it was helpful to you: [How can I view command prompt history after the window is closed on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1051939/how-can-i-view-command-prompt-history-after-the-window-is-closed-on-windows-10)

Comment: @Sunny I read through this thread. Why do you think it answers my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat %CMDER_ROOT%\config\.history | grep abc
```

In `Cmder::Cmder` sessions `history` is a doskey macro. The output of a macro cannot be passed using the pipe `|` but you could use the command that is the content of the doskey macro.

Referenced:
https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1770

Comment: I'm not a Cmder user, but if `history` is a `doskey` macro, then it is `doskey /history`, and that specific command does not produce any output *most of the time* when used in a pipe. In fact, its behaviour is erratic (Win10 21H2, `doskey.exe` 14.07.2022 20480 bytes). Other `doskey` commands, such as `doskey /macros`, do procuce output when used in a pipe. • So the answer does not seem to be quite accurate. • And if you want to use a macro in a pipe, the macro needs to contain the `$*` at the end or else the pipe specified on the command line will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The rough analog of `grep` in Windows is `find` and `findstr`. So just run `history 2>&1 | find "abc"` or `history 2>&1 | findstr abc`

The difference between them is that:

- `find` supports Unicode (UTF-16) but doesn't support regex, and `findstr` supports regex but not Unicode
- `find` requires quotes around the search string but `findstr` doesn't

[Why are there both FIND and FINDSTR programs, with unrelated feature sets?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121128-00/?p=5963)

In PowerShell there'll be a better solution: [Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7). It supports everything in `find` and `findstr` plus much more. And it doesn't have line length limitation

Comment: Both `history | find "abc"` and `history | findstr abc` bring back my entire cmder history, not just commands that start with 'abc'.

Comment: @CaleSweeney then probably cmder's history prints out to stderr. I don't use it so I'm not sure but if that's the case use `history 2>&1 | findstr...`